# Числительные русский язык и правильное их написание:

Tags: числительные

Как написать числительные?
1.По данным не хватило ПЯТИСТА/ПЯТИСОТ книг.
2.Более ПЯТЬДЕСЯТ одного процента опрошенных /более ПЯТИДЕСЯТИ одного процента опрошенных.
3.В ДВУХ ТЫСЯЧА СЕДЬМОМ году/ДВЕ ТЫСЯЧИ СЕДЬМОМ году.

Answer (score 1):

В каждом из приведенных Вами предложений правилен второй вариант